# What does "reach right out" mean?

Tags: meaning, idioms

> Wish that I could reach right out and touch it.
>
> When you see this little fellow, you'll want to reach right out and hug him to death.

Comment: "Reach out", but with emphasis.

Answer (score 1):

***Right*** in the cited example is really just an ***intensifier***. For a similar usage, consider...

> 1: *We left after paying the bill*
>    2: *We left **right** after paying the bill*
>    3: *We left **straight** after paying the bill*
>    4: *We left **immediately** after paying the bill*

Where the ***right, straight, immediately*** versions all *emphasize* how short the delay was between paying and leaving. In OP's example it's not so clear-cut exactly *what* is being emphasized / exaggerated, but a couple of reasonable paraphrasings are...

> 5: *I wish I **really** could reach out and touch it*
>    or
>    6: *I wish I could **stretch** out and touch it*

...but it's also quite reasonable to say ***to reach right out*** implies *to **stretch** out to reach*.

---

You may have noticed that although I used ***really*** as an intensifier in my own example #5 above, that same word is effectively being used with the *opposite* sense in the first sentence of my answer here (as is the word ***effectively*** in this very sentence). If you did notice that, and/or find this slightly confusing, you might like to have a look at [Opposite of “intensifier”?](https://linguistics.stackexchange.com/questions/9974/opposite-of-intensifier) as asked on SO Linguistics some years ago. Some words can either add ***or*** reduce emphasis, depending on the context in which they're used.

My point is that it's not always worth trying to assign specific *meaning* to words like ***right, really, fairly*** - sometimes all they're doing is adding or toning down the overall "force" of some assertion.